# Expand condition functions in LaTeX3

Tags: expl3

How to make `\foo_bar:` expand to `code a`?

```
\bool_new:N \foo_bool
\bool_set_true:N \foo_bool

\cs_new:Nn \foo_bar:
  {
    \bool_if:NTF \foo_bool
      { code~ a } { code~ b }
  }
```

**update:**

How about this one?

```
% `test.pdf` is in the current directory.
\cs_new:Nn \foo_bar:
  {
    \file_if_exist:nTF { test.pdf }
      { code~ a } { code~ b }
  }
```

(Complete question can be found in [Expand condition functions in xeCJK](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/380612/136923))

Comment: Could you 'expand' your fragment into a compilable document first, please ;-), but it should be `\cs_new_nopar:Nn \foo_bar:` rather. But it expands to `a` for me

Comment: Use `\cs_new:Nx` (or define a variant `\cs_new:Nf`)

Comment: Sorry, changing the question and piling up new requests is not the way to react to answers ;-

Comment: Sorry for that... But the second one is actually what I need to do and I think both questions are interesting.

Comment: `\file_if_exist:nTF` is not expandable.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Can you explain why `\bool_if:NTF` is expandable while `\file_if_exist:nTF` is not? Is there any method to "forcedly" expand `\file_if_exist:nTF`?

Comment: `\file_if_exist:nTF` has to perform "more work", more precisely has to change values of variables, which TeX does not let us do expandably for some reasons that are not easy to explain in 500 characters.  The best you can do is to bring it outside of the definition or of whatever else you want to use it for: `\file_if_exist:nTF { test.pdf } { \cs_new:Npn \foo_bar: { code~a } } { \cs_new:Npn \foo_bar: { code~b } }`.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch In fact I use another condition (`\xeCJK_family_if_exist:nTF` from `xeCJK` package), which will check whether an font family has been defined. If used in preamble, it will always return to the false-branch, or always gives `\cs_new:Npn \foo_bar: { code~b }`.

Comment: There is no simple general answer.  I suggest you try to make a complete question with all the details of what you are trying to achieve and post it as a separate question perhaps.  Unfortunately I won't have much more time, sorry about that.

Comment: @Stone-Zeng The underlying implementation requires we do a file opening, which isn't expandable as already mentioned. There are some pdfTeX primitives that might allow us to change that, but at present they are not available in all engines. Most file operations also need to track files, and that cannot be done expandably (needs an assignment), so we are not likely to 'push' the engine devs here.

Answer (score 2):

If the conditional value of `\foo_bool` should be frozen (expanded) in the definition of the macro, `\cs_new:Nx` is one possibility, if the macro should 'react' on the current value of `\foo_bool`, use `\cs_new:Nn` here.

I've changed the names to 'proper' `expl3` naming conventions.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\bool_new:N \l_stone_foo_bool
\bool_set_false:N \l_stone_foo_bool% Set to false, although false by def. 

\cs_new:Nn \foo_bar_current:
{
  \bool_if:NTF \l_stone_foo_bool
  { code~ a } { code~ b }
}

\cs_new:Nx \foo_bar_expanded:
{
  \bool_if:NTF \l_stone_foo_bool
  { code~ a } { code~ b }
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{}{%
  \foo_bar_expanded:
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\foobar}{}{%
  \foo_bar_current:
}

\bool_set_true:N \l_stone_foo_bool% For testing
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\foo\ and \foobar

\end{document}
```

`\foo` will expand to `code b` and `\foobar` will expand to `code a`, since setting the bool variable to true in the meantime, after defining `\foobar`.

[image]

Comment: FYI, we've moved away from encouraging `_nopar` use for argument-less macros because it adds things to think about with no benefit.  In the core `expl3` the only `_nopar` macros are user-facing ones or those that have to be compared to token lists.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: Eh, since which date you're encouraging users away from this? I was scolded two years ago, starting with `expl3`, for not using `_nopar` :-(

Comment: Sorry, we learn from experience.  I have no idea when we changed.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer As Bruno says, we realised a while ago that other than for setting up `xparse` and for some limited internal place, using `nopar` didn't really help. (For document-level interfaces it's different.) So it's not wrong to use `nopar`, it's just that we wouldn't do it now. As Bruno says, this is the 'experimental' part of `expl3`: there are changes as new ideas come forward.

Comment: @JosephWright: Removed the `_nopar` 'modifier'...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are defining a function that depends on some runtime options. The solution is to use `\cs_new:Nx` (which internally uses `\edef`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\bool_new:N \l_stonezeng_foo_bool

% true branch
\bool_set_true:N \l_stonezeng_foo_bool

\cs_new:Nx \stonezeng_foo_t:
 {
  \bool_if:NTF \l_stonezeng_foo_bool
   {
    \exp_not:n { code~a }
   }
   {
    \exp_not:n { code~b }
   }
 }

% false branch
\bool_set_false:N \l_stonezeng_foo_bool

\cs_new:Nx \stonezeng_foo_f:
 {
  \bool_if:NTF \l_stonezeng_foo_bool
   {
    \exp_not:n { code~a }
   }
   {
    \exp_not:n { code~b }
   }
 }

\cs_show:N \stonezeng_foo_t:
\cs_show:N \stonezeng_foo_f:

\stop
```

This will show on the terminal

```
> \stonezeng_foo_t:=\long macro:->code a.

> \stonezeng_foo_f:=\long macro:->code b.
```

Note `\exp_not:n`, so the inner code will not be expanded at definition time, but only upon usage.

Remember to use proper naming of variables and functions.