# Expand condition functions in xeCJK

Tags: expl3, latex3, xecjk

I am now writing a thesis template and I need to change the format of toc line. I use the following codes to do it:

```
% !TeX program  = XeLaTeX
\documentclass{ctexart}
% `\xeCJK_family_if_exist:nTF` will return true if `kai` is defined.
\setCJKfamilyfont{kai}{KaiTi}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \__foo_font_kai:
  {
    \xeCJK_family_if_exist:nTF { kai }
      { \CJKfamily{kai} } { \itshape }
  }

% Set the toc line format.
\keys_set:nn { ctex }
  {
    section / tocline = { \__foo_font_kai: \CTEXnumberline { #1 } #2 }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Title 标题}
\end{document}
```

The problem is `\__foo_font_kai:` can't be expanded properly, so in .toc file I can find

```
\contentsline {section}{\xeCJK _family_if_exist:nTF {kai}{\CJKfamily {kai}}{\itshape }\numberline {1}Title 标题}{1}
```

If compiled for the second time to get the correct toc, an error will occur:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \xeCJK 
                  _family_if_exist:nTF {kai}{\CJKfamily {kai}}{\itshape }\nu...
l.1 ...y {kai}}{\itshape }\numberline {1}Title}{1}

?
```

My solution is to define another "document command":

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand \foofontkai {} { \__foo_font_kai: }
```

Then the toc file will be

```
\contentsline {section}{\foofontkai \numberline {1}Title 标题}{1}
```

which can be compiled properly.

But I don't want it to be a user command (or keep the name `\__foo_font_kai:`), so what can I do?

I hope that the toc file can be like

```
\contentsline {section}{\CJKfamily{kai} \numberline {1}Title 标题}{1}
```

Related question: [Expand condition functions in LaTeX3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/380556/136923).

Comment: `\keys_set:nx`?

Comment: Using `\keys_set:nx` will lead to an error: `! Illegal parameter number in definition of \l__exp_internal_tl.`. I use `\keys_set:no` instead then, but it will not change the toc file.

Answer (score 1):

This might be too late to be helpful to OP, but only kills an unanswered question.

#### Solution:

```
\keys_set:nn { ctex }
  {
    section / tocline = {
      \protect \csname __foo_font_kai: \protect \endcsname
      \CTEXnumberline { #1 } #2 }
  }
```

This writes

```
\contentsline {section}{\csname __foo_font_kai:\endcsname \numberline {1}Title 标题}{1}
```

to `.toc` file.

#### Explanation:

When loading `.toc` file, `@` is the only special character whose catcode is (locally) set to letter. But a latex3 command requires both `_` and `:` have catcode letter. This can be avoided by using `\csname __foo_font_kai: \endcsname`.

However, since value of option `section/tocline` is expanded twice (with `\protect` let to `\@unexpandable@protect`) before written to `.toc`, an extra `\protect` is required for each of `\csname` and `\endcsname`.

This leads to solution `\protect \csname __foo_font_kai: \protect \endcsname`. There is no equivalence of `\protect` in latex3 and `\csname/\endcsname` cannot be substituted by `\cs:w/\cs_end:` because then each of them will require a `\csname ... \endcsname` protection, so `\protect \csname __foo_font_kai: \protect \endcsname` is the final result.

Further discussion: Changing both `_` and `:` to catcode letter (inside `\@starttoc`) when inputing `.toc` will prohibit user input such as `\section{$\alpha_2$}`.

Answer (score 1):

Just define a user level protected command:

```latex
% !TeX program  = XeLaTeX
\documentclass{ctexart}
% `\xeCJK_family_if_exist:nTF` will return true if `kai` is defined.
%\setCJKfamilyfont{kai}{KaiTi}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \foofontkai
  {
    \xeCJK_family_if_exist:nTF { kai }
      { \CJKfamily{kai} } { \itshape }
  }

% Set the toc line format.
\keys_set:nn { ctex }
  {
    section / tocline = { \foofontkai \CTEXnumberline { #1 } #2 }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Title 标题}
\end{document}
```